# json decode show null

Tags: php, json

I want to create an API which takes data from the Android app. but return $decoded show null.

```
 public function login(){

header("Content-type: application/json");

$content = stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$json = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $content);

$decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$response_array['content']=$content;
$response_array['decode']=$decoded;
return json_encode($response_array);

if(!is_array($decoded)){
    $response_array['decode']="fail";
    return json_encode($response_array);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXTFV.jpg)

Comment: You need to add the value `$json` to your post

Comment: There is probably an error in the data returned by the Andriod app. We don't have that data so we cannot tell what is going on.

Comment: There's a few odd things in that code. And since it's left undocumented, nobody knows what the pupose of the input rewriting was. Without reproducible input, this remains unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks out of order... try this:

```
public function login() {

    header("Content-type: application/json");

    $content = stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $json = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $content);

    $decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    if (!is_array($decoded)) {
        $response_array['decode']="fail";
        return json_encode($response_array);
    }

    $response_array['content'] = $content;
    $response_array['decode']  = $decoded;
    return json_encode($response_array);
}
```

The code you showed initially was returning before executing the handling for a failed `json_decode`.

Comment: you didn't need to copy everything. maybe just add what you changed?

Comment: Based on the formatting of the posted code, I'm not sure how abstractly I can effectively communicate reorganizing code blocks. Easier to just show it.